# Convert google direction JSON string url to URL

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, swift4

```
let stringOFDirection: String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=23.0723857839751,72.5160750795044&destination=23.057534,72.577191&waypoints=optimize:true|23.0557874,72.465833"

let directionsURL = URL(string: stringOFDirection)!
```

***The problem is directionsURL is nil***

I know solution is but, In this URL not working

Please help me!

Comment: Try replacing the commas with `%2C`

Comment: The problem with the "|" character, it's illegal in URL.

Comment: I think the `|` is the problem, at least it works without it, replacing it with `%7C` should do the trick, but it's not very dynamic.

Comment: Not working.... #Callam

Answer (score 5):

try adding this before you create the URL: `stringOFDirection.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!`

Comment: Don't forget to safely unwrap it. and accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

It should be as:

```
let stringOFDirection: String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=23.0723857839751,72.5160750795044&destination=23.057534,72.577191&waypoints=optimize:true|23.0557874,72.465833"

if let encodedStringOFDirection = stringOFDirection.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: . urlQueryAllowed), let directionsURL = URL(string: encodedStringOFDirection) {
    print(encodedStringOFDirection)

    // directionsURL is not nil and it works as expected...
}
```

the string should be encoded to let it recognizable for the URL.

Also, I would suggest to declare it with *optional binding* instead of force unwrapping it (`URL(string: stringOFDirection)!` with an exclamation mark) to make sure that you won't face a crash.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept an answer (green tick it) :) FYI, accepting an answer leads to: - gives the answerer +15 reputation points. - gives you (asker) +2 reputation points. - And the most important thing, it gives an indication for the viewers that this answer is the appropriate solution for this issue.